# Parsing Json : When i put the URL in browser doesn't work but when i put the url in jsonViewer i can see the data

Tags: java, android, url

Parsing Json : When i put the URL in browser doesn't work but when i put the url in jsonViewer i can see the data

Comment: define `doesn't work`. (typically, check the actual response from the server)

Comment: may be you should put the data here

Comment: The context is missing, bad question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the server handling the url only serves a response to requests with the Content-Type header of 'application/json'. http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/  might be automatically setting the Content-Type header in the http request to 'application/json'. So it works from http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/, but not when you simply paste the url in your browser. This is just a guess.